# Allow a web application to access files on a windows share

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, samba, jcifs

I'm trying to allow a web application running on Linux Ubuntu 10.04.4 and WildFly 9 to access files on a windows share using the JCIFS library ( https://jcifs.samba.org/ ). When testing Samba connections in isolation from the rest of our web application and not using WildFly everything seems to work ok.

The issue is if the connection fails when connecting from the WildFly container - the wildfly processing jumps to 100% CPU, and stays there. As of now this is 12 hours @ 100% CPU on our test system - so it's not timing out, if indeed something should be.

Using JCIFS in isolation from our webapp and Wildfly the protocol, authentication and file not found exceptions are caught and logged and it does not cause the java process to consume loads of CPU like the other scenario.

If anyone has any advise regarding their own experience or approaches to troubleshooting I could take I would be very grateful.

Comment: It's hard to say what the issue would be. You'd likely get some better ideas if you were to take a thread dump.